# Android ListAdapter cannot be applied to Parse FindCallback

Tags: android, parse-platform, callback

I am getting an error when trying to apply the results of a Parse query to a list adapter.  I want to assign the results of a Parse query to my list adapter on Android.  I cannot assign the results outside of the callback because the query is findInBackground and the results won't come back in time.  Below is the code I am using:

```
private void setupList() {
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    Log.i("Setup List", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());

    // Get the number of children the user has...
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Children");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null){
                Log.i("Find All", "Retrieved: " + list.size());
                if (list.size()>0){
                    numChildren = list.size();

                    adapter = new ListAdapter(this, createList(numChildren));
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
                Log.i("Find All", "Success!");
            }
            else {
                Log.i("Find All", "Failed!");
            }
        }
    });

    //Log.i("About to call the list", "Retrieved");
    //adapter = new ListAdapter(this, createList(numChildren));
    //listView.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
```

Comment: Do you get a crash?

Comment: No.  I am getting a warning.  Android doesn't like the use of 'this' in the callback.  I am thinking of using the context outside of the parse context but I am not sure what to use.

Comment: The error message is:  Error:(97, 51) error: incompatible types: <anonymous FindCallback<ParseObject>> cannot be converted to Context

Answer (score 0):

Try ParseQueryAdapter. This will autmatically populate your list when the results are found in the background.